# Как сохранять добавленные с помощью js input-ы после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Я добавляю input-ы по кнопке с помощью js. Как сделать так что бы при перезагрузке страницы они оставались?

```js
let coin = 0;

                           function addInput() {
                              let body = document.getElementById('input' + coin);
                              coin++;
                              if(body) {
                                 body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterEnd', `<div class="row gx-3 mb-3" id="input` + coin + `">
                                                   <div class="col-md-5">
                                                      <label class="small mb-1" for="inputFirstName">Параметр</label>
                                                      <input class="form-control" name="key` + coin + `" id="inputFirstName" type="text" placeholder="Укажите параметр" >
                                                   </div>      
                                                   <div class="col-md-5">
                                                      <label class="small mb-1" for="inputLastName">Значение</label>
                                                      <input class="form-control" name="value` + coin + `" id="inputLastName" type="text" placeholder="Укажите значение" >
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: end;">
                                                      <button class="btn btn-danger del-todo" style="margin-top: 1.7rem;" type="button" onclick="delInput(` + coin + `)">Удалить</button>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>`);
                              } else {
                                 coin = 0;
                                 let cardBody = document.getElementById('card-body');
                                 cardBody.innerHTML += `<div class="row gx-3 mb-3" id="input` + coin + `">
                                                   <div class="col-md-5">
                                                      <label class="small mb-1" for="inputFirstName">Параметр</label>
                                                      <input class="form-control" name="key` + coin + `" id="inputFirstName" type="text" placeholder="Укажите параметр" >
                                                   </div>      
                                                   <div class="col-md-5">
                                                      <label class="small mb-1" for="inputLastName">Значение</label>
                                                      <input class="form-control" name="value` + coin + `" id="inputLastName" type="text" placeholder="Укажите значение" >
                                                   </div>
                                                   <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: end;">
                                                      <button class="btn btn-danger del-todo" style="margin-top: 1.7rem;" type="button" onclick="delInput(` + coin + `)">Удалить</button>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>`;
                              }

                             
                        
                           }
                           function delInput(id) {
                              let div = document.getElementById('input' + id);
                              div.remove();
                           }
```

```html
<div class="card mb-4">
                                 
                                 <div class="card-body add" id="card-body">
                                 <button class="btn btn-blue add-todo mb-4" type="button" onclick="addInput()">Добавить</button>
                                    <div class="row gx-3 mb-3" id="input0">
                                       <div class="col-md-5">
                                          <label class="small mb-1" for="inputFirstName">Параметр</label>
                                          <input class="form-control" name="key0" id="inputFirstName" type="text" placeholder="Укажите параметр">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-5">
                                          <label class="small mb-1" for="inputLastName">Значение</label>
                                          <input class="form-control" name="value0" id="inputLastName" type="text" placeholder="Укажите значение">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: end;">
                                          <button class="btn btn-danger del-todo" style="margin-top: 1.7rem;" type="button" onclick="delInput(0)">Удалить</button>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
```

Comment: Сохранять данные в localStorage, а при загрузке читать данные и на основании их рендерить. Или если есть бэк с БД, сохранять значения в БД, а при открытии страницы получать данные и так же производить первоначальный рендреринг...

Comment: Возвращается [object HTMLDivElement], как его в нормальный html преобразовать?

Comment: Не очень понятно, где вы это получили. Надо в localStorage сохранять только ключи и значения, судя по вашему коду и переменная coin. Сохраняйте массив этих coin, а при загрузке страницы получайте данные и в цикле по шаблону рисуйте HTML элементы.